# Different libraries require different version of Protobuf (dependency conflict)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, protobuf-python

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
google-api-core 2.11.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-firestore 2.11.1 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-speech 2.19.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
googleapis-common-protos 1.59.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
grpcio-status 1.53.0 requires protobuf>=4.21.6, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
onnx 1.14.0 requires protobuf>=3.20.2, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-datasets 4.9.2 requires protobuf>=3.20, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-metadata 1.13.1 requires protobuf<5,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.19.0 which is incompatible.

I have tried installing different versions of protobuf, tried upgrading protobuf, tried upgrading all the libraries but nothing seems to work. I have been trying to install them in a virtual environment but i can not create different virtual environments since i need them in the same one. How to I deal with this dependency conflict issue?